# How to properly apply FancyBox2 to the images of a page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to use Fancybox2 to a set of 20 images but the images open without any effect.
Here's the complete code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flickr Feed</title>
    <link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <style>
        .image {
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
            border: solid 1px white;
            margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
        }
        .image:hover {
            border-color: red;
            background-color: rgb(204,204,204);
        }


    </style>

    <script src="../_js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox2/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var URL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne";
            var ID = "35034346867@N01";
            var jsonFormat = "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

            var ajaxURL = URL + "?id=" + ID + jsonFormat;
            $.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data)
                    {
                        $('h1').text(data.title);
                        $.each(data.items,function(i, photo)

                                {
                                    var photoHTML = '<span class="image">';
                                    photoHTML += '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m', '_b') + '">';
                                    photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m', '_s') + '"></a>';


                                    $('#photos').append(photoHTML);

                                }


                        );//end each

                        $('#photos').fancybox(
                                {
                                    openEffect:'none',
                                    closeEffect:'none'
                                }
                        );
                    }

            );//end get JSON


        }); // end ready
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>Missing<br>Manual</i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">
            <h1>Flickr Images</h1>
        <div id="photos"></div>
        <br class="clearLeft">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>JavaScript &amp; jQuery: The Missing Manual, by <a href="http://sawmac.com/">David McFarland</a>. Published by <a href="http://oreilly.com/">O'Reilly Media, Inc</a>.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the error message  'The requested content cannot be loaded.Please try again later' from the FancyBox2 script.

Comment: "Does not work" is not a description of a problem, and this question -- as an encapsulated entity -- has zero data.

Comment: Topic edited.Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Slightly better. "I can't" is still a far cry from usefulness though. And we do want code _in the question_. SO questions are not just for you -- they are for _everybody_ who might have your same problem. When that link breaks, this question will no longer say anything at all to help anybody else.

Comment: I have problems trying to post code that contains html.
What is the best way to post such code?
Thanks again.

Comment: Why not press the "?" button next to the post box? To get formatting help? Lots of people have spent lots of time formulating a list of Frequency Asked Questions, that explain how to post code on this code-related website.

Comment: Ok I figured it now.Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `fancybox` initialization code inside `getJSON` methos callback because thats where you are adding all the images. And the selector for `fancybox` plugin is wrong I believe it should be `#photos`. Try this.

```
       $.getJSON(ajaxURL,function(data)
                {
                    $('h1').text(data.title);
                    $.each(data.items,function(i, photo)

                            {
                                var photoHTML = '<span class="image">';
                                photoHTML += '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m', '_b') + '">';
                                photoHTML += '<img src="' + photo.media.m.replace('_m', '_s') + '"></a>';


                                $('#photos').append(photoHTML);

                            }


                    );//end each
                    $('#photos').fancybox(
                       {
                           openEffect:'none',
                           closeEffect:'none'
                        }
                    );
                }

        );//end get JSON
```

Comment: I always check for errors in the Javascript console before seeking any help.But chrome javascript console does not produce any errors.

Comment: Can you inspect `#photos` after the ajax call? Do you see appropriate markup inside it?

Comment: I fixed an error with my directories but now instead of the big image I get 'The requested content cannot be loaded.Please try again later'

Comment: That is a different server side issue, you should debug and find out.

Comment: Ok I found a solution!
I just changed ('#photos').fancybox to ('#photos .fancybox').fancybox

Comment: Ok I marked it.Give me some reputation if you believe I made the original post more clear.Thank you all for helping on this one.